# Пересечение css стилей

Tags: css, вёрстка

Я создал папку, в которой находятся файлы-css для разных компонентов, однако в одном компоненте работают стили из того файла, который я не подключал к этому компоненту. Подскажите пожалуйста, как ограничить стили для каждого компонента в отдельности.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не подключенные стили не работают вообще ни для кого. Покажите что-нибудь из вашей проблемы чтобы можно было дать более объективный ответ.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Используйте БЭМ: https://ru.bem.info/methodology/quick-start/

Comment: Но вообще если Вы не подключали, но всё равно работает, значит Вы точно куда-то его подключили (или подключали, но не очистили кеш в браузере).

Comment: С вашего позволения добавлю скрины. На первом слайде, тот компонент в котором применяются не подключенные там стили, на втором скрине, те стили которые я туда подключил. На третьем тот компонент, куда я подключил стили которые работают, на четвертом те стили которые работают. На пятом скрине тот компонент который я запускаю и слева те стили которые работают, а те которые я подключал к этому компоненту почему то зачеркнуты.